# How to use Chinese in Latex formulas?

Tags: formulas

I am writing a Chinese formula in Latex.

```
\begin{equation}
    平均访问延迟 = 缓存命中时间 + 缓存失效率 × 失效代价
\end{equation}
```

I've tried multiple methods but still can't render.

[image]

I'm using the template(in overleaf) here.

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/2022-peking-university-master-thesis-template-iofu728-pkuthss/rwfvbkpzydpf

Since this template is too large, I can't give a small example, but it can be tested directly on overlead.

```
\documentclass[fontset=fandol,ugly,language=chinese]{pkuthss}
```

And compiled using `XeLatex`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is always a good idea to post a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and not just a few code snippets. Also note that links to projects are problematic, because questions on this site should be self-contained so that future visitors can still use them (along with the answers) as reference to solve their problems.

Comment: The solution is most likely to use `\textrm{平均访问延迟}` in your formula.

Comment: wow,  really thanks! It works!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template is a Chinese one. So it's not necessary to do any setting on Chinese fonts more.

For the Chinese input in equations, you just need to use the commands like `\text{}`(or `\textrm`), `\textit{}`, `\textsf{}`, `\textbf{}` and so on. For example, your texts should be input as

```
\begin{equation}
    \text{平均访问延迟}=\text{缓存命中时间}+\text{缓存失效率}\times\text{失效代价}
\end{equation}
```

Note that, Chinese punctuations should also be put in `\text{}` (or `\textrm`), `\textit{}`, `\textsf{}`, `\textbf{}` and so on,  for example, `。` should be input as `\text{。}`.

Further more, some related and difficult inputs should be noted. If you don't want the shape or family or series of fonts for Chinese characters in equations to be changed with the environments, for example, the theorem and definition environments, you should put them in `\text{\normalfont }`(or `\text{\normalfont\rmfamily }`), `\text{\normalfont\itshape }`, `\text{\normalfont\sffamily }`, `\text{\normalfont\bfseries }`, and so on. This is different from the English input in equations for which `\mathrm{}`, `\mathit{}`, `\mathsf{}`, `\mathbf{}` would work well but don't work for Chinese characters. Of course,  we seldom use Chinese characters as fixed and stable mathemcatical symbols. See the following MWS.

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\begin{document}
{right input: \bfseries\itshape $\text{\normalfont\rmfamily 中文}$ $\text{\normalfont\sffamily 长城}$ \text{中文} \textsf{长城}}

{wrong input: \bfseries\itshape $\mathrm{\text{中文}}$ $\mathsf{\textrm{长城}}$ \text{中文} \textsf{长城}}

{wrong input: \bfseries\itshape $\mathrm{\text{中文}}$ $\mathsf{\textsf{长城}}$ \text{中文} \textsf{长城}}

{right input: \bfseries\itshape $\mathrm{Chinese},\mathsf{Wall}$ \textrm{Chinese} \textsf{Wall}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be: Change the 1st line in the preamble to `ctext`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ctexart}
...

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Then, when you write an equation, use `\textrm{}` to include terms in Chinese. For example,

```
\begin{equation}
    \textrm{平均访问延迟}=\textrm{缓存命中时间}+\textrm{缓存失效率}×\textrm{失效代价}
\end{equation}
```

Reference: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Chinese.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The [source code for the `pkuthss` class](https://gitea.com/CasperVector/pkuthss/src/branch/master/tex/pkuthss.cls) shows that it already uses CTeX beneath the hood. Specifically, it uses `ctexbook`. So, your solution with `\textrm` would still work without needing to change the document class.

Comment: @gz839918 Specifically, Chinese document classes such as `ctexart`, `ctexrep` and `ctexbook` all invoke the `ctex` package implicitly which  is a package for Chinese writings in LaTeX.